# ¿Que significan if(cin.fail() && cin.rdstate()) en el siguiente código?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include "conio.h"

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void opciones(){
  cout << "1) Ingresar datos" << '\n';
  cout << "2) Calcular varianza" << '\n';
  cout << "3) Calcular desviación" << '\n';
  cout << "4) Salir" << '\n';
}

int numeroDatos(){
  int cantidad = 0;// la cantidad es de tipo int 
  cout << "Número de datos a ingresar:" << '\n';
  cin >> cantidad;// Permite al usuario ingresar la cantidad
  return cantidad;//Permite retornal la función
}

int * obtenerDatos(int cantidad){
  int * datos = new int[cantidad];//crear un nuevo arreglo, usando el puntero
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    std::cout << "Ingrese dato " <<i+1 <<": " << '\n';//permite ingresar los datos
    cin >> datos[i];
  }
  return datos;
}

float obtener_promedio(int cantidad, int *datos){
  float suma = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    suma += datos[i];
  }
  return suma / cantidad;
}

float obtener_varianza(int cantidad, int *datos){
  int n = cantidad;
  float promedio = obtener_promedio(n, datos);
  float varianza = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    varianza += pow((datos[i] - promedio), 2.0);
  }
  return varianza / (n -1);
}

float obtener_desviacion(int cantidad, float varianza, int *datos){
  if(varianza == 0){
    float varianza = obtener_varianza(cantidad, datos);
  }
  return sqrt(varianza);
}

int  main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int opcion = -1;
  int cantidad = 0;
  int *datos;
  float varianza = 0;
  float desviacion = 0;
  char pause = 0;
  do{
    opciones();
    cin >> opcion;
    if(cin.fail() && cin.rdstate()){//
         cout << "NO ES UN NUMERO" << endl;
         opcion = -1;
    }
    switch (opcion) {
      case 1:
          cantidad = numeroDatos();
          datos = obtenerDatos(cantidad);
          break;
      case 2:
          varianza = obtener_varianza(cantidad, datos);
          cout << "varianza: " << varianza << '\n';
          cout << "continuar..." << endl;
          getch();
          break;
      case 3:
          desviacion = obtener_desviacion(cantidad, varianza, datos);
          cout << "Desviación: " << desviacion << '\n';
          cout << "continuar..." << endl;
          getch();
          break;
      default:
        cout << "No existe opción" << '\n';
        break;
    }

 } while (opcion != 4);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hola Laura , para que tu respuesta sea bienvenida por la comunidad , te recomiendo editar esta pregunta y formatearla con las herramientas que te entrega stack. Saludos! O/.

Comment: ¿Qué supuesta mejora incorpora el cambio que acabas de hacer? La pregunta no tiene ni pies ni cabeza. Por favor revisa [ask]

Comment: @Laura He revertido la pregunta a su enunciado original, pues la habías cambiado por completo y entonces ya no tenía sentido la respuesta que aparece más abajo (y que aceptaste). Si quieres preguntar otra cosa, abre una nueva pregunta en lugar de editar la anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cin.fail():
```

Retorna `true` si el ultimo comando `cin` falló.

```
cin.rdstate():
```

Retorna una combinacion de las banderas: `std::ios_base::badbit`, `std::ios_base::eofbit` y `std::ios_base::failbit`

Generalmente, estos checks se utilizan cuando se leen archivos.

Comment: Esto no responde lo que dice el titulo de la pregunta.

Comment: @Xam Ahora ya si. Laura había editado la pregunta y la había cambiado por otra. He revertido la edición